# How to test responsiveness of a website page locally on iphone mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am working on a page and trying to make it mobile responsive. It's working fine in Android phones but when I am opening in iphone it hides below Buttons or space. I also tried to test that page locally on iphone using ipconfig using IPv4 Address but getting CORS error. Is there a way I can test the responsiveness of a page in Iphone locally.

Comment: https://responsively.app/

Answer (score 2):

You can open your developer console in responsive mode and simulate various screen widths there. This works on most modern browsers. Consult your browser of choice's online documentation for specific instructions on how to do this for that particular browser.

This methodology is not always 100% accurate but it usually gets very close.

You can also download a simulator of the mobile platform you are testing and run on your computer. These simulators are very accurate as far as showing you the exact behavior that the phone will experience.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.browserstack.com/
https://saucelabs.com/

These Tools can help to test local/live URLs in cloud based real devices.